# Collapse a horizontal menu for response design

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I have a menu which looks like this:

```
|Home|Options|Settings|Tools|Preferences|Edit|
```

That's fine when a phone has lots of horizontal space, but when a device with a narrow viewport accesses the page, I want the menu to look like

```
|Home|Options|Settings|+MORE+|
```

Where clicking the "MORE" menu displays the other items in a vertical drop down.

I don't want to set manual breakpoints, because I have no idea how wide the individual menu items will be when displayed.

My menu is currently just a set of `<li>` in a `<ul>`

The CSS for horizontal layout is

```
#menu ul, #menu li { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
#menu ul { overflow: auto; }
#menu li { float: left; }
#menu  a { display: block; padding: 0.5em; text-decoration: none; border-right: 1px solid #fff; font-size: 110%; }
```

I'm reluctant to use something like jQuery - even when minimized, it's still a significant overhead for older mobile browsers.  Media Queries are also problematic for some phones, so I would like to avoid relying on those.

Any thoughts on CSS and (simple) JavaScript to automatically hide elements depending on the browser's width?

Comment: Media Queries actually have quite good support. 

You can check out some navigation patterns here: http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/web/complex-navigation-patterns-for-responsive-design/ & http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/web/responsive-nav-patterns/

Comment: On new devices, yes. But the majority of the world uses old mobile devices - see http://www.slideshare.net/bryanrieger/rethinking-the-mobile-web-by-yiibu

Comment: I commend you on your concerns for accessibility, but the majority of devices that are over 5 years old, from Nokia, Sony Ericsson, LG etc.  can run Java applications like Opera Mini 4+ just fine. I've been using the same Nokia Supernova 7210 S40 phone for the past 3 years; the browser I use, Opera Mini 4.4 (it's actually an old version; the later versions can even run a little JS...live! Which is quite impressive imo) is more than capable of rendering complex web pages pretty well. I mainly use it in 'single-column' mode which is pretty self explanatory and in many cases an excellent feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, you can do it with no JavaScript at all, just with [**media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries) (which really [*have excellent support*](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries) + this solution I am presenting is a mobile first one) and [**`:nth-last-child`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:nth-last-child) (which again is even [supported by Opera Mini](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)).

## [demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/3744065)

(resize to see how it works)

You'll need to have a structure like this:

```
<nav id='menu'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Options</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Tools</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Preferences</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>+ MORE +</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Then you'll need to select the **Tools**, **Preferences** and **Edit** and set their `display` to `none`:

```
#menu li:nth-last-child(-n+4):not(:last-child) { display: none; }
```

`li:nth-last-child(-n+4)` selects only the first four list items from the end. You add the `:not(:last-child)` condition to that because you want the **+ MORE +** list item to be shown.

In order to better understand structural pseudo-classes, you can play around with [**this tool**](http://lea.verou.me/demos/nth.html).

Finally, you'll need to use a media query to change the display settings for larger screens:

```
@media (min-width: 30em) {
    #menu li:nth-last-child(-n+4):not(:last-child) { display: block; }
    #menu li:last-child { display: none; }
}
```

I am using an `em` based media query and not a `px` based one for two reasons:

- one, [**this article**](http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/);
- two, my own site looks like crap on zoom because I used `px` based media queries on it a year ago;

---

**EDIT**: In order to make the menu expand on click and to make the number of menu elements shown vary with screen width, I have changed the structure a bit more:

```
<nav id='menu'>
    <a tabindex=1 class='ctrl' href='#'>+ MORE +</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#' class='menu-link'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' class='menu-link'>Options</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' class='menu-link'>Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' class='menu-link'>Tools</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' class='menu-link'>Preferences</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' class='menu-link'>Edit</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And also changed the CSS a bit:

```
#menu .ctrl { float: right; }
#menu ul, #menu li { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
#menu ul { overflow: auto; }
#menu li { float: left; }
#menu li:nth-last-child(-n+5) { display: none; }
#menu a {
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    font-size: 110%;
}
#menu li a { display: block; }
#menu li:first-child a { border-left: 1px solid #fff; }
#menu .ctrl:focus, #menu .ctrl:active { display: none; outline: 0; }
#menu .ctrl:focus ~ ul li, #menu .ctrl:active ~ ul li { display: block; }

@media (min-width: 15em) {
    #menu li:nth-child(2) { display: block; }
}
@media (min-width: 20em) {
    #menu li:nth-child(3) { display: block; }
}
@media (min-width: 25em) {
    #menu li:nth-child(4) { display: block; }
}
@media (min-width: 30em) {
    #menu .ctrl ~ ul li { display: block; }
    #menu .ctrl { display: none; }
}
```

## [**demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3748950)

(I've also added a background with vertical lines at every 5em just to make it clear how wide the screen is when resizing the browser window)

This method should work without JavaScript - tested that in desktop browsers, Opera Mobile, Android browser and iOS Safari. I don't know about Opera Mini though - I'll have to test that.

**EDIT#2**: No, it doesn't work in Opera Mini for me (the menu is collapsed, but clicking the **+ MORE +** link does not expand it). Tried to make it work with JavaScript (no library), but that also doesn't work in Opera Mini (though it works on desktop browsers).

**EDIT#3**: Also tried to do the same thing using jQuery. This time it also works in Opera Mini. Really slow (at least for me), but it works. This is what I used:

```
$('.ctrl').click(function() {
    $(this).css({'display': 'none'}).next().children().css({'display': 'block'});
});
```

---

**EDIT#4**: Now tried the `:target` method - [**demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3749419) (also CSS-only). Works fine on my laptop using Chrome (haven't tested in another desktop browser), doesn't work in Opera Mini (menu is collapsed, clicking the **+ MORE +** link does not expand it). Works in Opera Mobile though.

Comment: Thank you. That's very comprehensive. Is there any way to get it to reveal more items incrementally without having to manually set the min-width?  For example, On a screen 30em wide, I only want 4 items - if it's 50em I want 5, etc.

Comment: Sorry, one other point - clicking on the "more" link doesn't expand the menu. Can I use Target selectors for that?

Comment: #1 If there is a way, I cannot think of it right now. #2 Just with CSS, that requires changing the structure a bit more http://dabblet.com/gist/3748950 (after the menu is expanded, clicking anywhere else collapses it again).